# How to create a custom slider control in silverlight 4 for WP7?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-4.0

I need a custom control where I can select a value from a horizontal scrolling text. Basically I am building a converter app in WP7 and want a control which allows me to select a value from a scrolling text. The values should scroll horizontally and as soon as the value comes in focus should get selected. Any advice would be of great help?

Comment: The text of this question bears little similarity with the question in its title.  There is very little "question" in the text (amounts to "advice please").  "Scrolling text" means what?  Text in text box that has a __scroll__ bar?  Text that is moving in some kinda of looping animation?  What?  What value should get selected?  More detail, consistency and clarity is required here.

Answer (score 1):

check this may help you 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165826/Custom-Gauge-Controls-for-Windows-Phone-7-Part-I

Also you can check the [customize the slider control as in below link](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Customizing-WP7-Slider-in-different-ways)